# No rawData retrieved from nativescript-mediafilepicker

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to use [nativescript-mediafilepicker](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker/blob/master/README.md)

I have the following in my `component.ts`:

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
        this.mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
        this.mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
            let results = res.object.get('results');
            console.log(results[0]);
        });
    }
```

```
onSelectTap(): void{
        let options: ImagePickerOptions = {
            android: {
                isCaptureMood: false, // if true then camera will open directly.
                isNeedCamera: true,
                maxNumberFiles: 1,
                isNeedFolderList: true
            }, ios: {
                isCaptureMood: false, // if true then camera will open directly.
                isNeedCamera: true,
                maxNumberFiles: 1
            }
        };
        this.mediafilepicker.openImagePicker(options);
    }
```

The restult of `console.log(results[0])` is:

```
 {
   "type": "image",
   "file": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20200605_123955.jpg",
   "rawData": {}
 }
```

What am I missing here?  The end goal for me is to have a base64 string of the image.  Thanks in advance